# Spring data JPA batch insert is very slow

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to read Excel file with 700K+ records and batch insert those in MySQL database table.

Please note, Excel parsing is fast and I can get my entity objects in an `ArrayList` within 50 seconds or so.

I am using Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA.

Below is my partial `application.properties` file:

```
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=1000
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=true
```

and my partial `Entity class`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "WHT_APPS", schema = "TEST")
public class WHTApps {

    @Id
    @TableGenerator(name = "whtAppsGen", table = "ID_GEN", pkColumnName = "GEN_KEY", valueColumnName = "GEN_VAL")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "whtAppsGen")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "VENDOR_CODE")
    private int vendorCode;
    .
    .
    .
    .
```

Below is my `DAO`:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class JapanWHTDaoImpl implements JapanWHTDao {

    @Autowired
    JapanWHTAppsRepository appsRepo;

    @Override
    public void storeApps(List<WHTApps> whtAppsList) {
        appsRepo.save(whtAppsList);

    }
```

and below is `Repository` class:

```
@Transactional
public interface JapanWHTAppsRepository extends JpaRepository<WHTApps, Long> {

}
```

Can someone please enlighten me as to what I am doing incorrect here?

**EDIT:**

Process does not finish and throws error eventually:-

```
2017-08-15 15:15:24.516  WARN 14710 --- [tp1413491716-17] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
2017-08-15 15:15:24.516 ERROR 14710 --- [tp1413491716-17] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 107,472 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 107,472 milliseconds ago.
2017-08-15 15:15:24.518  INFO 14710 --- [tp1413491716-17] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2017-08-15 15:15:24.525  WARN 14710 --- [tp1413491716-17] c.m.v.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester  : SQL State '08007' of Exception tested by statusOnException() implies that the database is invalid, and the pool should refill itself with fresh Connections.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Communications link failure during rollback(). Transaction resolution unknown.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar:5.1.43]
    .
    .
    .
    .
    2017-08-15 15:15:24.526  WARN 14710 --- [tp1413491716-17] c.m.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection     : [c3p0] A PooledConnection that has already signalled a Connection error is still in use!
2017-08-15 15:15:24.527  WARN 14710 --- [tp1413491716-17] c.m.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection     : [c3p0] Another error has occurred [ com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Communications link failure during rollback(). Transaction resolution unknown. ] which will not be reported to listeners!

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Communications link failure during rollback(). Transaction resolution unknown.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
```

Thanks

Comment: It's right there, in the TOC, under "batching" or "batch inserts". Ctrl-F is your friend. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#batch

Comment: You are saving 700K records in a single transaction. What happens is 1 record is added to the first level cache. Then another one, which first check if there is a dirty record in the case. Now with 1 or 10 records that is fast, now imagine that with 10000 records or 100000 or 700000. You shouldn't store 700000 records at once with hibernate. You should create chunks of data to persist ideally the same size as your batch size. See https://vladmihalcea.com/2017/04/25/the-best-way-to-do-batch-processing-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Answer (score 3):

I would point one more thing. The problem could be not only hibernate but DB.

When you insert 700k objects in one transaction it could be stored in DB's rollback segment waiting for the transaction commit.

If possible split the logic to have commits in the middle.

Create 1k sized sublists from the main list, save the sublists and commit after each sublist saving.

Comment: I can see that process is not finished and it throws error eventually, please see my updated question. May be I will try out what you suggested...

Comment: Could be connection timeout as well. Try first with a small list e.g. 1k whether it works

Comment: To store around 1200 records in database time taken is ~7 seconds

Comment: 7*700 seconds. What is your default DB connection timeout? Anyway it's better to split the process with chunks insert/commits

Comment: It is really slow... I am using @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE) could that be cause behind slowness?

Comment: After splitting the records into chunks of 1500 records and having batch_size of 1500, records are getting inserted into DB in chunks; but still it is very slow. Whole 700K records might take ~50 to 60 mins to complete. Is that because I am using @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)?

Comment: I can't say whether it depends on strategy. Try to get rid of the @GeneratedValue and see what is the result. Do you have any triggers on the DB?

Comment: Yeah tried without @GeneratedValue, performance more or less remains same. I don't have triggers in DB. Now checking with 2 threads (not sure it will help)

Comment: Tried with two threads, little bit improvement in performance [1 thread = ~62mins AND 2 threads = ~43mins for 700K+ records]. However more than 2 threads do not work and result in weird "Communications link failure" error.

Comment: 2 more ideas. Could you try with pure SQL? Measure importing 1k records to see whether it's hibernate problem or DB problem. Split to a smaller chunks